# Is there any dataset for images which contains each object name?

Tags: data-request, images

Is there any image dataset which has labels for image itself and also includes  labels for every object in that image? I need a dataset which is publicly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large image dataset is available [at Image Net](http://www.image-net.org/). It does require free registration, and there is a note that the company does not own the copyright.  The images are open to the extent that you can [download them](http://image-net.org/download-features) and use them for research purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Did you search wikimedia commons? https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

You can download them via wikimedia dumps: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html

Answer (score 1):

The NIST handwritten digits use the digit as label ... but that's obviously only 10 labels.